# DB Update Exception in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard-2.0

I am writing a .Net Standard library. I wanted to use the Entity framework for performing DB operations.  For performing the DB operations, I want to use the Entity framework.

```
//Intro.cs in SQLiteExample(.NetStandard library)
namespace SQLiteExample
{
    internal class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blogging.db");

        }
    }

    public class BlogOperations
    {
        BloggingContext bloggingContext = new BloggingContext();

        public async void CreateBlog(string url)
        {
            using (var db = bloggingContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inserting a new blog");
                db.Add(new Blog { Url = url });
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async void CreateBlogWithPost(String url, string title, string content)
        {
            using (var db = bloggingContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inserting a new Blog with a post");
                Post post = new Post
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Content = content
                };
                Blog blog = new Blog
                {
                    Url = url
                };
                blog.Posts.Add(post);
                db.Add(blog);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        }

        public async Task<Blog> ReadBlogs()
        {
            using (var db = bloggingContext)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Querying for a blog");
                Blog blog = await db.Blogs
                    .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
                    .FirstAsync();
                return blog;
            }

        }

        public List<Blog> ReadAllBlogs()
        {
            using (var db = bloggingContext)
            {
                var blogs = db.Blogs
                    .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
                    .ToList();
                return blogs;
            }

        }

        public async void UpdateBlog(string url, string title, string content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updating the blog and adding a post");
            var db = bloggingContext;
            var blog = await db.Blogs
                .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
                .FirstAsync();
            blog.Url = url;
            blog.Posts.Add(
                new Post
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Content = content
                });
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async void DeleteFirstBlog()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete the blog");
            var db = bloggingContext;
            var blog = db.Blogs
                .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
                .FirstAsync();
            db.Remove(blog);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void DeleteSpecificBlog(string url)
        {
            var db = bloggingContext;
            var blog = db.Blogs
                .Where( b => String.Equals(b.Url, url))
                .First();
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "";

            str += "Url" + Url + "\n";
            str += "Rating" + Rating + "\n  Posts: \n";

            foreach(Post post in Posts)
            {
                str += "Title" + post.Title + ",";
                str += "Post" + post.Content + "\n";
            }

            return str;
        }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am accessing the functions from BlogOperations using functions in UWP Application where I am referring to the .Net Standard library.

[image]

on button click I am adding the record in blogs using :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        blogOperations.CreateBlog(UrlTb.Text);
}
```

After the button click, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: See this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/crud-operation-using-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: Please share at least some code or reference to an example to pick up from there

Comment: I am the above error when I am trying to perform CRUD operations.